# Mesh Array Modifier with Fit Curve modifier strings objects through center, not origin

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am using Array modified and Fit Curve modifier to place multiple meshes on a bezier curve.  Unfortunately, blender is passing the curve through the centers of the generated objects, and I need the objects to be placed so that the curve passes through the origin, not center.

Is there a way to do this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by *center*? The geometric center of an object? If so, does it not correspond to the object's origin?

Comment: Try using a *Follow Path* constraint

Comment: By "center" I mean the approximate visual center of the object.  I have no idea what point blender is using, but put an array of cubes on a spline and you will see. The spline goes through the middle, regardless of the origin.

Comment: "Follow Path Constraint" seems to be for animation. Does it also work for modifiers?

Comment: No, follow path works for individual objects. However you can make the origin of the objects go to the center of mass in an object by pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Alt`+`C` and selecting *Origin to Geometry*

Comment: That's good to know...but I need to do it the other way...adjust the center of mass to the origin.  I don't think that is going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I was just being stupid...I'm answering the question in case someone else looks at this issue.

I had set the origin of the bezier to the endpoint of one of the handles...I thought it was on the actual endpoint of the curve.

As a result, even though the origins were lined up and scaled & rotated the same, the modifier was placing the objects with an offset.  It LOOKED like it was going right through the center of the mass of the created objects, but this was just a coincidence.

So...if you have this problem, check your origins again!  Make sure the endpoint of the spline is placed exactly where you want it and its origin is on the endpoint, not the handle.

thanks for the replies.